# Transformation of spinor reps and why the Dirac rep is its own conjugate

Tags: special-relativity, representation-theory, spinors, majorana-fermions, clifford-algebra

In Polchinski's String Theory volume 2, appendix B, on page 433 (in the section on Spinors and SUSY in various dimensions, specifically the subsection on Majorana spinors) he says:

"It follows from eq B1.18 that the spinors $\xi$ and $B^{-1}\xi^*$ transform in the same way under the Lorentz group, so the Dirac representation is its own conjugate."

I don't follow this at all. Could someone explain it please? I don't understand either the claim that those two objects transform the same way under the Lorentz group, nor the claim that thismeans the Dirac rep is its own conjugate.

Background from the previous two pages in the book:

- eqn B.1.18: $B\Sigma^{\mu \nu}B^{-1} = - \Sigma^{\mu \nu \ *}$
- B denotes either B1 or B2, where $B_1 = \Gamma^3 \Gamma^5.. \Gamma^{d - 1}$, $B_2 = \Gamma B_1$.
- We also know that $B_1 \Gamma^{\mu}B_1^{-1} = (-1)^k \Gamma^{\mu \ *}$ and $B_2 \Gamma^{\mu}B_1^{-1} = (-1)^{k+1} \Gamma^{\mu \ *}$.
- $\xi$ was defined by the fact it was annihilated by all the $\Gamma^{\mu \ -}$. It was then used to define a basis for the representation space for the Clifford Algebra.
- $d = 2k + 2$, where d is the spacetime dimension.

EDITED: To add the last bullet point saying what k is.

Comment: What is $k$ as in $B_1 \Gamma^{\mu}B_1^{-1} = (-1)^k \Gamma^{\mu \ *}$?

Comment: I edited the post, thanks.

Comment: What is the metric of this $d = 2k + 2$ spacetime. Euclidean? Minkowski? Please be specific. In other words, what is the Clifford Algebra in concern? Is it Cl(d,0), Cl(0,d), Cl(2k, 2), or Cl(2, 2k)?

Comment: The metric is diag(-1, 1, 1, 1, ..., 1).

Comment: If metric is diag(-1, 1, 1, 1, ..., 1), and lets say d=4 (k=1). Therefore $B_1 = \Gamma^3$. It's easy to check that $B_1 \Gamma^{\mu}B_1^{-1} = (-1)^k \Gamma^{\mu \ *}$ does not hold.

Comment: And how is $\Sigma^{\mu \nu}$ defined? Is it $\Sigma^{\mu \nu} = \Gamma^\mu\Gamma^\nu$ or $i\Sigma^{\mu \nu} = \Gamma^\mu\Gamma^\nu$?

Comment: $\Sigma^{\mu \nu} = -\frac{i}{4}[ \Gamma^{\mu}, \Gamma^{\nu}]$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $D: G \to V^*$ be a representation of a Lie group $G$.

**Definition:** A representation is its own conjugate (a.k.a. pseudo-real) if there exists a matrix $B$ such that for all $g \in G$, we have $D(g)^* = B D(g) B^{-1}$.

Given an element $\Sigma_{\mu\nu}$ of the Lorentz algebra, an element of the Lorentz group is given by $D(\Lambda ) = \exp [ \frac{i}{2} \omega^{\mu\nu} \Sigma_{\mu\nu} ]$. Now, Polchinski proves that there exists a $B$ such that $\Sigma_{\mu\nu}^* = - B \Sigma_{\mu\nu} B^{-1}$. This implies
\begin{align}
B D(\Lambda) B^{-1} &= B \exp \left( \frac{i}{2} \omega^{\mu\nu} \Sigma_{\mu\nu} \right) B^{-1} = \exp \left( \frac{i}{2} \omega^{\mu\nu} B \Sigma_{\mu\nu} B^{-1} \right) \\
&= \exp \left( - \frac{i}{2} \omega^{\mu\nu} \Sigma_{\mu\nu}^* \right) = \exp \left( \frac{i}{2} \omega^{\mu\nu} \Sigma_{\mu\nu} \right)^* = D(\Lambda)^* . 
\end{align}
Therefore, by definition, the Dirac representation is pseudo-real.

Under Lorentz transformations, $\xi$ transforms as
$$
\xi \to D(\Lambda) \xi.
$$
Similarly $B^{-1}\xi^*$ transforms as
$$
B^{-1}\xi^* \to B^{-1} \left( D(\Lambda) \xi \right)^* = B^{-1} D(\Lambda)^* \xi^* = B^{-1} B D(\Lambda) B^{-1} \xi^* = D(\Lambda) \left( B^{-1} \xi^* \right)
$$
Thus, $\xi$ and $B^{-1} \xi^*$ have the same transformation law.

Comment: How does one see that the spinors $\xi$ and $B^{-1}\xi^*$ transform in the same way under the Lorentz group?

Comment: @Gleeson - added.